# VS code extension dependencies not being deployed when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tsconfig

Running `Visual Studio Code 1.52.1`.

I created a simple `VS Code` extension as described in [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension). Then I added a dependency as shown below. **The problem is that this dependency does not seem to get deployed when debugging.**

---

**package.json**

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@types/markdown-table": "^2.0.0"
}
```

And the actual import looks like this:

```js
import * as table from 'markdown-table'
```

Then I hit `F5` just as described in the linked tutorial. When my registered command is run, I get the following error message:

> Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.hello-world' failed: Cannot
> find module 'markdown-table'

For completeness, here is the generated **tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode-test"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to add a `preLaunchTask`.

**For Example in `.vscode/launch.json`**:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Run Extension",
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"],
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: build"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Useful. But I just now realized that I only imported the types and not the actual package. I.e. this was missing: `"markdown-table": "^2.0.0"`